# Canceling the default submit button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, defaultbutton

I have an ASP.NET application where there's a few ASP.NET buttons and several plain HTML buttons.  Anytime there's a textbox where a user hits enter, the ASP.NET button tries to submit the form.

I know I can change the `defaultButton`, but I don't want there to be any default button.  I just want it so when the user presses enter it doesn't do anything.

I've tried setting `defaultButton` to blank, but that doesn't seem to work.  How do I prevent the form from being submitted by the ASP.NET button when enter is pressed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the button's UseSubmitBehavior = false

```
btnCategory.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
```

Comment: That does indeed produce the behaviour needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx

Comment: @RyanSmith sometimes it's difficult to search for negatives, like "don't have a submit button" because of the number of ways the negative can be articulated.

Comment: An additional note: ASP.Net's ImageButton doesn't have a UseSubmitBehavior attribute. If you're using one of those, see the "hidden dummy button" solution below. also see: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561400/how-to-disable-submit-behaviour-of-aspimagebutton)

Answer (score 26):

Here is what I used to fix this problem.

```
<form runat="server" defaultbutton="DoNothing">
        <asp:Button ID="DoNothing" runat="server" Enabled="false" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: Nice hack! I had an asp.net imagebutton in my masterpage that kept submitting whenever the enter button was clicked on any page. However, this little trick fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried literally everything but for whatever reason (bug) or something, ImageButtons continued to be fired off as DefaultButtons even when you don't set them as such.  I tried all above attempts, this is the only thing that worked. As much as I hate use a dummy asp:Button it worked perfectly...

Comment: Kinda hate to use hacks like that, but this is the quickest solution when you have imageButtons.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with an ImageButton on my MasterPage (the Logout button) being set as the default button (so whenever someone pressed Enter, it would log them out). I solved it by using the following line in the Page_Load event on every child page, which is a bit of a work-around, but it works:

```
Form.DefaultButton = cmdSubmit.UniqueID;
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TXT_Quality" runat="server" Width="257px" 
onkeypress="return key_Pressed(event, this);">
</asp:TextBox>   

function key_Pressed(e, textarea)
 {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) 
    { 
       return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error when navigating to another page after having set my login form's Sign In button as the default as described above. My fix was to test in the Master Page's load event and if the contained page was not my login page, to set the default back to nothing like this:

```cs
if (Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath != "~/Login.aspx") {
    Page.Form.DefaultButton = "";
}
```