# Controlling the submit behaviour of an ImageButton in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a image button in a page which can be triggered on mouse click, by default it gets triggered on enter press also which i want to disable.
how to make the submit behaviour of the `aspx:image` button false

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561400/how-to-disable-submit-behaviour-of-aspimagebutton

Comment: ^^^ Wow. It's an exact duplicate.. diffuerent username..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Pretty freakin scary, right? makes you wonder..  are you and I the only ones on SO? seems we're following each other around..lol

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(function(){
        $('#<%=imgBtn.ClientID%>').keydown(function(e){
            if(e.which==13)
            {
                 return false;
            }
        });
    });
```