# How to deactivate button click when pressing enter on webpage

Tags: asp.net

On a webpage there is a text box and a button. when enter is pressed it activates the button1_click - how can I stop this?

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"   Text = "ADD" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: You can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561400/how-to-disable-submit-behaviour-of-aspimagebutton) for an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in JQuery, it's very simple

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

You have to add this in documentready and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UseSubmitBehavior property of the button:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx