# how I can disabled default submit in asp:ImageButton when user hit enter key asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I find this but It doesn't work with me

[How to disable submit behaviour of asp:ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561400/how-to-disable-submit-behaviour-of-aspimagebutton)

and this my html

```
<td class="style101">  
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPost" runat="server" Height="30px" 
         ToolTip="posting" ImageUrl="~/images/postvoucher.jpg" 
         onclick="ImageButton4_Click" Width="39px" />
</td>
```

Comment: please give some more informations, what does not work, with what browser, what error did you get ? what do you have try ?

Comment: you can check KeyPress Events cab you show the `codebehind` that you have associated with the onClick also based on the link that you provided not sure why it doesn't work for you.. did you add the `javascript code` please show all relevant code

Comment: I tryed to add the jquery  in body and before style  jQuery.fn.DisableEnterKey =
    function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).keydown(function(e)
            {
                var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                // return false for the enter key
                return (key != 13);
            })
        })
    };

// You can then wire it up by just adding this code for each control:
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#Txtamount').DisableEnterKey();
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813324/296861) in your question is to disable pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key inside textbox.

Another approach is you can disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key press in an entire page. *Obviously, you only want that feature in a specific page.*

For example,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on("keyup keypress", function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

</script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPost" runat="server"
    OnClick="ImageButton4_Click" ... />
```

Comment: I added the code you gave it to me but the enter still working I will describe what exactly I want the web form include drop down list , 4 text box and image button  when am in first text box and the user hit enter key goes directly to image button i want to disable that

Comment: My code works. Create a new ASPX page (without master page) and test it. The problem is if your existing ASPX page has JavaScript error, other JavaScript will stop working too. Also make sure you include jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it from code behind. It will prevent the post back to the server ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87xh91hb(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
imgBtnPost.Enabled = false;
```