# Disable default button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Canceling the Default Submit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473388/asp-net-canceling-the-default-submit-button)

I have only 1 button in my ASP.NET page but when I click "Enter" key the button click function is talking place. I don't want that. Only manual click must work. How to make this?

Comment: If the .NET way suggested in the accepted answer of the above question fails, you can use the JS way suggested in [Robert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473388/asp-net-canceling-the-default-submit-button/1473463#1473463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body onkeypress="return CancelReturnKey();">

  <script type="text/javascript">
        function CancelReturnKey() {
            if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
                return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Lol...! JavaScript for this too? I found this better UseSubmitBehavior = "false"

Comment: Yes that's true no need to add some JS for your page just change the default behavior for that button ;)

Comment: But finally your code only worked for me... Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: and, what if you have a multiline textbox ? you are blocking the new line key!

Answer (score 33):

Set the button's **UseSubmitBehavior** = "false"

Comment: I guess this is the direct way to change the button default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the links

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/985791.aspx/1