# Enter causing postback even if no submit button is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a form in asp.net page. Whenever enter key is pressed the page is posted back.

I don't have any submit button in my form and using javascript to submit form.

```
        <div class="row-fluid" align="center">
            <a id="saveConfirm" class="textDecorationNone">
                <div class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Add
                </div>
            </a>
            &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnCancel_Click">
                <i class="icon-remove"></i>&nbsp;Cancel
                </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>


row('#saveConfirm').click(function (){
    //submit form
});
```

Comment: Zero experience in ASP.net, googled `Enter causing postback even if no submit button is present` your title and the first response was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be addressed I believe with the accepted solution of the following post:

[ASP.Net page enter key causing post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back)

Quoting:

- You could set the [DefaultButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) on the Form or a Panel. This way you have full control what happens.
- Set [UseSubmitBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)="False" on your Buttons. This disables the "AutoPostback" on Enter.

A possible javascript solution for ASP.NET is covered under this solution: 
[Disable default button in ASP.NET [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555706/disable-default-button-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

use Updated Panel which avoid postback while enter.