# Facebook openId integration button click event is being firing by default

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, openid

I  have used facebook open id button on one of my asp.net site. when i am pressing enter key by default event for this button is being called. I couldn't figure how to to make it out of focus. I tried very hard. I have other button thats needs to fire on default enter key and used asp panel for the same. my code is here      
Please suggest me how to make it out of focus..

Answer (score 0):

Since you listed no code, I'll take my guess.

It sounds like you're having more of a problem with the [Default Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473388/asp-net-canceling-the-default-submit-button) than OpenID integration. Try that link for several ways to cancel the submit / default button behavior.