# DefaultButton when using masterpages ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I am using masterpage in my solution. In that masterpage there is a imagebutton named "Save" using as the saving option for all my pages, which is set as Defaultbutton in masterpage. The problem is that, in one of my page i have a textchanged event which i want to work when pressing "Enter" key. But when i press "Enter" key "Save" function works after the textchanged event. I dont want to happen "Save" function on "Enter" key press.  I don't want there to be any default button on my page

Comment: Not sure, do you want to remove the default button for that particular page ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta :- yes. I want to remove defaultbutton for that particular page

Comment: Ok, Maybe you can do something like `this.Form.DefaultButton = null` on page load

Comment: @V4Vendetta :- i tried, but now textchanged event is not working when pressing "Enter" key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to prevent enter key while you are work in text-box
just put this function in ur page.

just add `onkeydown` event to ur text-box

```
<input type='text' onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" />
```

another one
this function need `jquery`

```
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button's **UseSubmitBehavior = "false"**

similar question is here [Canceling the default submit button in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473388/asp-net-canceling-the-default-submit-button)