# when I pressed enter it goes direct to the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing web form in asp.net inside it there are drop down list , text box and buttons when I pressed enter after text box it goes direct to buttons how can I stop that I didn't put that button as default button but I need to know why is that happening ?

Comment: an answer here which may be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473388/asp-net-canceling-the-default-submit-button

Comment: You can check if it's set as `DefaultButton` property

Comment: that's the default behaviour for a form... if you ever have a submit button around... you might need to explicitly set the buttons to type="button"

Comment: no it I checked the property before and you can take a look  of the html                                                                                                         <td class="style101"> 
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnupdate" runat="server" Height="42px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/saveupdate.jpg" onclick="ImageButton3_Click1" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPost" runat="server" Height="30px" ToolTip="post" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/postvoucher.jpg" onclick="ImageButton3_Click" Width="39px" />
                     </td>

Comment: and asp:ImageButton is designed to behaves by default as a submit button...

Comment: ok there is no way to stop the default behaves???